# Using comparator in upper_bound STL

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

I'm trying to make a program that gives the **last element that** is less than or equal to our given value.

According to the definition of lower_bound, it gives the first element that is greater than or equal to the given key value passed. I created a comparator function

```
bool compare(int a, int b) {
    return a <= b;
}
```

This was passed in my lower bound function:

```
int largest_idx = lower_bound(ic, ic + n, m, compare)
```

On execution, it was giving me the last element which was less than equal to my m (key value). Isn't this opposite to how lower_bound works ? Lower bound is supposed to give me the first value for my comparison or does the comparator actually change that?

Comment: `[ic, ic + n)` represent increasing or decreasing range?

Comment: increasing range

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn "first" into "last", you have two options. First, you can use `std::upper_bound` and then take the previous element (see below). Second, you can use [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
const auto pos = std::lower_bound(
    std::make_reverse_iterator(ic + n),
    std::make_reverse_iterator(ic), m, compare);
```

where `compare` is

```
bool compare(int a, int b) {
    return b < a;
}
```

With this comparator, `std::lower_bound()` returns the iterator pointing to the first element that is not greater (= less than or equal) than `m`. On the reversed range this is equivalent to returning the iterator pointing to the last element satisfying this criterion in the original range.

Simple example:

```
int ic[] = {1, 3, 3, 5};
// pos
// m = 1    ^ 
// m = 2    ^
// m = 3          ^
```

> How do I modify that search criteria (change `<=` to something else)?

`std::lower_bound` finds the first element in the range (partitioned by the comparator into `true`, ..., `true`, `false`, ... `false`), for which the comparator returns `false`. If your criterion can be rephrased in this language, you can use `std::lower_bound`.

Suppose we have a range `1 3 3 5` and we replace `<` with `<=` (your version of `compare`). Then we have:

```
        1 3 3 5
m = 2   T F F F
m = 3   T T T F
m = 4   T T T F
```

For `m = 3` and `m = 4`, `std::lower_bound` will return the iterator to `5`, i.e. past the last `3`. In other words, `std::lower_bound` with default `<` being replaced with `<=` is exactly what `std::upper_bound` with default `<` is. You can advance the resulting iterator by `-1` to get the last element (but be careful about corner cases like `m = 0` in this example).

> How do I change whether I want the first or last element

It always returns the first element for which the comparator returns `false`. You can either reverse the range or find the first element that follows the one you want to find.

Comment: How does this comparator actually fit into the lower_bound() function, I thought it would just change the criteria of finding the first element

Comment: What I wanted to know was how comparators fit in the lower_bound program in general. Its really going over my head as to how I can modify comparison functions inside the lower_bound()

Comment: @shawnindamnen, what do you mean by "fit"?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear, I just want to know like how does the comparator function actually influence the lower_bound(), like in general it searches for the first element that is greater than or equal to it. 

How do I modify that search criteria (change <= to something else) and how do I change whether I want the first or last element

Answer (score 0):

The comparator must not check for equality, use less than.

Also the data shall already be sorted or must at least be partitioned according to the comparator.

cf. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Comment: The range must not be sorted, it must be partitioned by the comparator. This is a weaker requirement. For integers, both `<` and `<=` are valid partition functions.